# I have a general question about dplyr mutating joins

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

The documentation for the dplyr package for mutating joins states that for using "by" that "A character vector of variables to join by" is needed.

This however does not seem to be the case.

It seems to work with a numeric or a dbl variable, i.e. column. By this I mean the common column (idenifier) that is used to join the dataframes.

This a glimpse of a portion of the two dataframes. nomem_encr is the common identifier.

```
df1
Rows: 2,525
Columns: 11
$ nomem_encr <dbl> 800054, 800170, 800186, 800204, 800228, 800274, 
$ mj16a093   <dbl+lbl>  4,  4,  3,  4,  2,  5,  5,  3,  5,  3,  6,  
$ mj16a094   <dbl+lbl>  3,  4,  2,  4,  2,  5,  5,  2,  3,  2,  6, 

df2
Rows: 6,092
Columns: 3
$ nomem_encr <dbl> 800009, 800015, 800042, 800054, 800057, 800085, 
$ cv16h101   <dbl+lbl>   2,   3,   5,   6,   7,   6,   0,   6,   5,   
$ cv16h044   <dbl+lbl>  6,  7,  7,  8,  0,  7,  5,  4,  7,  8,  7,  

df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "nomem_encr")
```

Is it best to convert to a character, or does it not matter? My assumption was that the values just needed to be unique identifiers.

Comment: numeric you mean by the column index? Can you show an example?

Comment: yes sorry. I saw too late that that was not clear. I mean that the column (variable) is a numeric or a dbl, i.e. the common variable for joining the dataframes. I found it strange that the documentation states "A character vector of variables to join by".

Comment: Rows: 2,525
Columns: 17
$ nomem_encr <dbl> 800054, 800170, 800186, 800204, 800228, 800274, 80~
$ mj16a093   <dbl+lbl> 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 5, 3, 6, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5~
$ mj16a094   <dbl+lbl> 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5~
$ mj16a095   <dbl+lbl> 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 5~
$ mj16a096   <dbl+lbl> 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 4~
$ mj16a097   <dbl+lbl> 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 6, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5~
$ mj16a098   <dbl+lbl> 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4~
$ mj16a099   <dbl+lbl> 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4~

Comment: nomem_encr being the common variable to join the dataframes ...

Comment: Please add the new information in your question, not the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "by" : "A character vector of variables to join by"`

This means that when you write the join, your `by` argument needs to be a character vector and **NOT** your column to be a character. for example

```
left_join(d1, d2, by = c('ID', 'Latitude'))
```

You are passing a character vector to the `by` argument. The columns being numeric does not matter

Comment: You beat me to it. I'll amend my answer to include some other options.

Comment: Yes It took me a while to understand what the OP meant

Answer (score 1):

##### Using Left Join

The wording could probably be better, but what is meant by the help page is that you have to supply a character vector for the name of the variable, but the variable type can be anything. Basically you are telling the `by` argument "join by this variable explicitly". A visual from R for Data Science by Hadley Wickham may help illustrate how this is accomplished with `left_join`, where the "key" is the `by` column necessary for joining:

[image]

An easy example can be found with the `nycflights13` datasets. First you can load the tidyverse and nycflights13 packages.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
```

Then you can check which columns are shared by the `flights` dataset and the `planes` dataset.

```
#### Check Joinable Columns ####
colnames(flights)
colnames(planes) # share tail number
```

We find they both contain "tailnum":

```
> colnames(flights)
 [1] "year"           "month"          "day"            "dep_time"      
 [5] "sched_dep_time" "dep_delay"      "arr_time"       "sched_arr_time"
 [9] "arr_delay"      "carrier"        "flight"         "tailnum"       
[13] "origin"         "dest"           "air_time"       "distance"      
[17] "hour"           "minute"         "time_hour"     
> colnames(planes) # share tail number
[1] "tailnum"      "year"         "type"         "manufacturer" "model"       
[6] "engines"      "seats"        "speed"        "engine"
```

We can combine both datasets with `by` via a `left_join` with the tailnum variable like so:

```
#### Join Two Dataframes ####
flight2 <- flights %>% 
  left_join(planes,
            by = "tailnum")
flight2
```

Which gives us our combined data:

```
# A tibble: 336,776 × 27
   year.x month   day dep_time sched_de…¹ dep_d…² arr_t…³ sched…⁴ arr_d…⁵ carrier
    <int> <int> <int>    <int>      <int>   <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <dbl> <chr>  
 1   2013     1     1      517        515       2     830     819      11 UA     
 2   2013     1     1      533        529       4     850     830      20 UA     
 3   2013     1     1      542        540       2     923     850      33 AA     
 4   2013     1     1      544        545      -1    1004    1022     -18 B6     
 5   2013     1     1      554        600      -6     812     837     -25 DL     
 6   2013     1     1      554        558      -4     740     728      12 UA     
 7   2013     1     1      555        600      -5     913     854      19 B6     
 8   2013     1     1      557        600      -3     709     723     -14 EV     
 9   2013     1     1      557        600      -3     838     846      -8 B6     
10   2013     1     1      558        600      -2     753     745       8 AA     
# … with 336,766 more rows, 17 more variables: flight <int>, tailnum <chr>,
#   origin <chr>, dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>,
#   minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>, year.y <int>, type <chr>,
#   manufacturer <chr>, model <chr>, engines <int>, seats <int>, speed <int>,
#   engine <chr>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​sched_dep_time, ²​dep_delay,
#   ³​arr_time, ⁴​sched_arr_time, ⁵​arr_delay
```

##### Generalizability of Other Joins

This is accomplished by all other joins in `dplyr` by the way, but how it does this is different depending on the join you use. The `left_join` function includes all rows in x (the first dataframe used, in this case `flights`) whereas a `right_join` joins by y (the second dataframe `planes`). Here are the three other examples, which I have labeled by their usage:

```
#### Alternative Joins ####
flights %>% 
  right_join(planes,
             by = "tailnum") # includes all rows in y

flights %>% 
  inner_join(planes,
             by = "tailnum") # includes all rows in x AND y

flights %>% 
  full_join(planes,
            by = "tailnum") # includes all rows in x OR y
```

Play around with them and see which is the best for your use case.

Comment: wow thanks for the fast answer. much appreciated! I get it. I thought it was strange that it had to be a character, but now I get it ...

Comment: Glad it could be helpful!

Comment: If you felt Sotos answer was helpful, you are encouraged to accept his/her answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it (Sotos answered first so it should be the accepted answer imo).